# What distribution looks like a uniform distribution with decaying density at the extremes?

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, graphing-functions, parametrization

I was wondering if there exists a distribution with  this general shape:

[image]

I want to model something using a prior distribution that is uniform in its interior, and then smoothly (but relatively quickly--hopefully theres a parameter for this) decays to $0$ at the extremes. Does such a distribution, defined on $\mathbb R$, exist?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function . Normalize to get a distribution.

Comment: @lisyarus This is close, but (and I don't have a more formal way to describe this, but I hope you understand) a bump function seems to decay quickly as you move away from $0$. I'm looking for a function that decays relatively slowly until the extremes are approached.

Comment: Can you define it piecewise?

Comment: @Patricio Something like $\frac{a}{1+\exp(-(x+5))}$ for negative $x$ and $\frac{a}{1+\exp((x-5))}$ for nonnegative $x$ (and suitable $a$), but I was wondering if there was some cute parametric distribution that already existed.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking. Sorry, can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at the "smooth transition function" mentioned in the article [linked to](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) in the bump-function article. The one with the (a, b, c, d) parameters seems like what you're looking for.